# Fortigate 100D - L2TP range

Tags: fortigate

I need a specific number of hosts connected on Fortigate with L2TP/IPsec, about 300.
I tried to configure this range via console

config vpn l2tp ... set sip 10.0.0.1 ... eip 10.0.1.254

It says that network should be /24 and this way i can't connect my 300 hosts.

Is it a limitation or i missed something ?
Can i bypass this configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seem a FortiOS limitation.

> The start and end IPs in the PPTP address range must be in the same
>   **24-bit subnet**, for example, 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254.

From http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20Help/PPTP_L2TP.104.07.html